# If I mmap a memory region with no access bits set, does mlockall still force it to be backed by physical memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap, mlock

By default Linux doesn't actually back the pages allocated with `mmap` with any physical memory until the first time they are accessed. However you can force it to do so preemptively by calling `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE)`.

It is a common pattern to create guard pages by `mmap`ing memory but not setting any of the access bits. Because these pages are not actually going to be used, it would be nice if `mlockall` ignored them and still didn't actually back the pages. Can I assume this? Does the Linux kernel go out of its way to make this true?

Comment: In general, physical memory isn't allocated until something uses it.

Comment: @Barmar: sure but the whole point of mlock is changing that.